# Is Raiden viable for one way micro payments?

Tags: scalability, sidechain

As an example if we wanted to increase participation on the Ethereum stackexchange, we could set up a contract to make micro payments out to stack members based on reputation/badges.

This would only make sense in a no-fee or extremely low fee scenario. Is Raiden the correct way to approach such a solution or are there other viable existing alternatives on ethereum?

Answer (score 2):

This would work using Raiden Network, check out the [API documentation](https://raiden-network.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_api.html) to get some ideas on interacting with Raiden. If you have direct channels to the users then there wouldn't be any fees (although opening a direct channel is an on-chain interaction). It'd be in the scenario where if there's no direct path that you might have to pay a very low amount of fees.